# input hidden string via sys.argv in python

Tags: python, input, command-line-interface

I need to input the password via the command line and use it in the program via `sys.argv[2]`.

The problem with CLI is that the password is displayed in clear text.

Below is the code :

```
import sys
user_args = sys.argv[1:]
username, password = user_args

print username
print password
```

Take a look :

[image]

Comment: When you say `is that the password is displayed in clear text` you mean that it's shown when it's being typed?

Comment: @Borja, yes..exactly.

Comment: You can't do that then.

Comment: Yeah...got that. Still, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the getpass module (https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/getpass.html)

```
import getpass
password = getpass.getpass('Enter password: ')
```

Comment: I know about get pass, but the requirement is something like : script.py username password

Comment: If you type in "script.py username password" your python script is not yet running, so I don't see a way you can achieve this independent of your command line interpreter.